# How can I retrieve the is_sfparam-content while printing RECN contracts?

Tags: abap, guid

How can i retrieve the is_sfparam-content, either using query or function module.

then will be passed as a parameter to cl_recp_data_cn_general=>get_contract.
do you have any idea? Where can I get that is_sfparam-content?

Thanks

```
CALL METHOD cl_recp_data_cn_general=>get_contract
  EXPORTING
    id_guid     = is_sfparam-content
  IMPORTING
    es_contract = contract
  CHANGING
    cf_error    = lf_error.
```

Comment: Look at the tables: `DOCGUID` or `SFDOCGUID`, field `DOCGUID` or `SFDOCGUID` for the latter.

Comment: The import parameter `id_guid` is asking for a 'Globally Unique Identifier' aka GUID. You use a GUID when you need to identify an object/component with a unique id. And `is_sfparam` is a textvalue (`TYPE sfparam`) which contains a reference to the object that is transferred to the smart form.

Comment: hello @Legxis is there any way that I could get the value to be passed in is_sfparam, whether fm or via query?

Answer (score 0):

This guid paramater brings no sense as it is generated **in runtime**. You can check this yourself by putting breakpoint at the first line (e.g. line 102) of method `cl_recp_data_cn_general=>get_contract` and checking `id_guid` var in debugger. It will be different with each run of preview in `RECN` tcode.
Check also line 11 of `CONSTRUCTOR` method of `CL_RECP_SF_DOC` class, it is executed during each form generation.

The real contract object lays in variable `go_busobj` of program `SAPLRECA_BDT_APPL_TOOL` which brings RECN functionality and it is **global** i.e. it is loaded into memory constantly while RECN is running, just passing doc object into called methods thru the call stack, which you can follow in debugger.

Where really form generation takes place is `CL_RECP_SF_JOB` class, for preview it is `_FP_PREVIEW` method, for print it is `_FP_PRINT`. For example, in preview method form FM is called in that place

[image]

What you need to do if you want to call arbitrary contract print-form, which is what I assume you want to do by asking this question:

1. Find out smartform FM name by putting breakpoint in the above line
2. Build parameters for this FM calling. The only obligatory parameter is `LS_SFPARAM-CONTENT` which is the GUID.

You can generate this GUID manually by creating `CL_RECP_SF_DOC` object, let it be `io_doc` var. The constructor of this object has input parameter `is_doc` which should be filled according to the attributes of contract which you want to print, and which are stored in `VIBDRO` and `VICNCN` tables.

After creating this object pass its attribute `io_doc->md_guid` to `ls_sfparam-content`, generate other parameters with `CL_RECP_SF_JOB->_sf_get_form_param` and

3. Run the smartform FM /`1BCDWB/SF000000XX` found at step 1 with these parameters

I didn't check all these steps by myself but I believe it should work.